# simplify preg_replace to clean up url

Tags: php

I have part of a url like this: `2000+%26+Sale+%26+7867876876` and I want to clean it up like this `2000-Sale-7867876876`

so far I managed to do that using these two lines

```
$canonical = preg_replace( '/\+/', '-', $canonical );
$canonical = preg_replace( '/\%26-/', '', $canonical );
```

Is this the best method or could I simplify into just one line?

Answer (score 0):

```
$canonical = str_replace('+%26+', '-', $canonical);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's really all you need to change...

```
$canonical = "2000+%26+Sale+%26+7867876876";
echo str_replace("+%26+","-",$canonical);
// 2000-Sale-7867876876
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace like this also

```
$canonical = preg_replace( '/\+%26+-/', '', $canonical );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`urldecode`](http://www.php.net/urldecode) and replace everything that isn't alphanumeric:

```
<?php
    $url = '2000+%26+Sale+%26+7867876876';

    $canonical = preg_replace(
        array('/[^\w- ]+/', '/[- ]+/'), 
        array(''          , '-'), 
        urldecode($url)
    );

    var_dump($canonical); //string(20) "2000-Sale-7867876876"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/Zumxw1n8)

It's one line, but it's multiline-padded here for readability.